# Context grammar for specific language

Tags: computer-science, grammar, context-free-grammar

I can't understand simple problem. I have to indicate grammar for the following
words

a)    `(ab)^2i c,  i>=1`

for i=1  `ababc` for i=2 `ababababc`

```
   S -> abA
   A -> ab | abc | c
```

b)    `a^(m-1) b^(m+1) a^n b^n,  m>=1  n>=1`

for i=1  `bbab` for i=2 `abbbaabb`

```
   S -> AbbAaAb
   A -> ba | ab | a
```

Can someone check these exercises and give me feedback. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First one will generate `(ab)^i`, and you just want even numbers of `ab` pairs in words, so you have to define it as

```
S -> ababA
A -> ababA | c
```

You also have to use `A` on the right hand side, in the second rule, as your rules will create a word of max length 5.

Second one

```
S -> AbbB
A -> aAb | epsilon (empty string)
B -> aAb
```

For the first part of the word, you always need `bb` on the right hand side. You generate `a^n b^n` left from it.

For the second part of the word, we reuse the nonterminal `A`, but we make sure there's at least one `ab` in the word part - that's why `B`.